# how to find out solution ionic 2 An error occurred while running cordova prepare ios (exit code 1). application not build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a new application in Ionic 2 and my application build IOS command

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

but `defined output in error`

[image]

What is the best solution?

Comment: are you by chance building ionic1?

Comment: no... my project is in ionic 1 but environment of my computer is ionic 2

Comment: you mean cli version is ionic 2.x?

Comment: already are available in config.xml file  line :     <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" /> and image are available in folder in images name : drawable-xhdpi-icon.png

Comment: I find out error solution : 
**step.1** defult ionic 2 splash images  size 2732*2732  
**step.2** add images path : Myproject\ resource\ splash.png  
**Step.3** after  then command run ionic cordova resources ios 
**step.4** ionic cordova buils ios